# document is not defined in ReactJS chrome extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently building a chrome extension using React.js. I need to run a script to get the input element of the active tab, so in my *background/index.js* file I tried to do a `document.getElementsByTagName("input")` but I received:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined

I don't use ReactDOM because it's not a file to render so I don't know how to access to the document.

Help would be appreciated !

Comment: Use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), not the background script. And don't load your background script as a content script.